# Why doesn't "sudo su" in a shell script run the rest of the script as root?

Tags: shell, shell-script, sudo, root, su

A sample script can be as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo su
ls /root
```

When using `./test.sh` as the normal user, instead run `ls` as super user and exit, it switches to root; and when I logout, it executes `ls /root` as the normal user.

Can anybody tell me about the mechanism about it?

Comment: `sudo su` makes my eyes hurt.

Comment: It is used because people don't know sudo well enough, and so they need a way to run su on systems where root is secured by a deliberately corrupted password.  But yes sudo "redundifies" the use of su.

Comment: Can't you just use `sudo -s`, though?

Comment: @Johan, I often use `sudo su` because I am more used to the options of `su` than I am of those of `sudo`. I know the options of sudo well enough, but I can type the su ones faster. But yes I guess that means I don't know sudo well enough.

Comment: i have found one or two applications that i couldn't install via sudo, so i needed to actually sudo su to root in order to install them.

Comment: @acolyte, wrong, in that case you need `sudo -i` :-)

Comment: @guntbert ???  what does the -i option do?  and i'm not sure why you're saying i'm wrong, because it worked beautifully.

Comment: @acolyte: "wrong" because you didn't **need** it, you just needed `sudo -i`, which gives you a shell with root privileges.

Comment: This just proves the need for sudo su.  People don't understand sudo and its options.  sudo requires to be configured.  sudo isn't available everywhere.  I don't even know the difference between sudo -i and sudo -s

Comment: I just checked the sudo man page.  It appears `sudo -i` is akin to `su -` while `sudo -s` operates like `su` (without the dash)

Comment: what exactly does `su -` do?

Comment: possible cross site duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988249/how-do-i-use-su-to-execute-the-rest-of-the-bash-script-as-that-user

Comment: Why I "sudo su root": Ubuntu. http://askubuntu.com/questions/86095/does-executing-sudo-su-and-su-root-do-the-same-thing

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The commands in a script execute one by one, independently.  The Script itself as the parent of all commands in the script, is another independent process and the su command does not and can not change it to root: the su command creates a new process with root privileges.

After that su command completes, the parent process, still running as the same user, will execute the rest of the script.

What you want to do is write a wrapper script.  The privileged commands goes into the main script, for example `~/main.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
ls /root
```

The wrapper script calls the main script with root permissions, like this

```
#!/bin/sh
su -c ~/main.sh root
```

To launch this process you run the wrapper, which in turn launches the main script after switching user to the root user.

This wrapper technique can be used to turn the script into a wrapper around itself.  Basically check to see if it is running as root, if not, use "su" to re-launch itself.

$0 is a handy way of making a script refer to itself, and the whoami command can tell us who we are (are we root?)

So the main script with built-in wrapper becomes

```
#!/bin/sh
[ `whoami` = root ] || exec su -c $0 root
ls /root
```

Note the use of exec.  It means "replace this program by", which effectively ends its execution and starts the new program, launched by su, with root, to run from the top.  The replacement instance is "root" so it doesn't execute the right side of the ||

Comment: fwiw, an addendum to this point. If I were writing a script like it I would just do an if statement at the beginning that checks $EUID and if it's not zero sudo itself and exit, otherwise continue with the script execution.

Comment: Agreed, and I will update the answer to explain this.

Comment: Perhaps its a bit archaic but i love absolute paths to every executeable so someone cant change the ~/main.sh script into something nefarious. Attacking the USER part of the script

Comment: You may also want to catch the arguments that were passed to it by including a reference to $*

Comment: @JoelDavis I always run into the wall of "what if there are spaces characters in the arguments".  I've never found a satisfactory solution.  Once I wrote a script which put out its arguments into a temp file, one argument per line, and then called whatever it needed and passed to that final script the argument of what file to read to find the original arguments in.

Comment: @artifex  You can always find one more issue you need to cater for.  Where do you stop?  Portability to zOs?

Comment: @johan You stop when your security policy is satisfied. It may range from i-dont-care to treat-the-system-as-already-compromised.

Comment: @JoelDavis - I've spent many hours dancing with embedded blanks. Using "$@" for argument lists helps. Using eval for commands helps a lot too. The newest trick someone showed me is to put all your arguments into an array and then reference the array as "$ARRAY[@]". That also helps make blanks behave. To detail all of this would require a separate question.

Comment: In setups where the default user has to use sudo (e.g. Ubuntu, AWS AMIs), the solution can be amended to read: ```[ `whoami` = root ] || exec sudo su -c $0 root```

Answer (score 24):

Use the following in script.

```
sudo su <<HERE
ls /root
HERE
```

The code between the HERE block will be run as root.

Comment: `sudo su` is calling two programs.  Use `sudo -s <<HEREDOC` or `su user <<HEREDOC` ... Stupid 5 minute limit.

Comment: Remember the commands in heredoc cannot indent, even with `<<-`. And args passed to the main process can pass to subshell of sudo su if `HERE` is without quotes.

Answer (score 6):

Without further arguments `su` will run the login shell for root. That's what the first line of your script actually does. When you exit, the login shell closes, su returns and your script continues execution, that is with the second line: `ls /root`. I think you can simply `sudo ls /root` to do what you want.

Comment: Yeah, I know I can do this for `ls`, but this is just a sample. In fact I need to do a lot more things with root privilege:-) So I prefer @Ankit's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Once you fire `sudo su` a new process with the effective `userid (euid=EUID)` of super user forked, hence we have new bash running at different process id `(pid=PID)` associated with the same terminal `(tname=TTY)`.

**Explanation**

Suppose after firing `ps -A | grep bash` you have `21460 pts/2 00:00:00 bash` as output. Now, when you execute `./test.sh` both commands `sudo su` and `ls /root` will get spooled to `PID 21460`. After execution when you have `root` as active user hit `ps -A | grep bash` again, you will notice a new bash running on `PID say, 21570`. Exiting from `root bash` will kill newly forked bash reverting to `user's bash` and hence executes the spooled command `ls /root` before releasing the prompt.

Comment: If using su or sudo was "persistent" in bash (or anywhere else) it would create many more problems than it solved. You need to do the minimum possible as root for safety and security. The main point of having su and sudo (other than security!) is to make you think carefully about what needs root privileges.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a script to run with root privileges, put this in the beginning of it:

```
if [ ! $(whoami)=”root” ]; then
    exec sudo ”$0” ”$@”
    echo ”Error: failed to execute sudo” >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

This will re-execute the script with the same parameters, but prefixed with `sudo`. If the `sudo` command succesfully starts, it replaces the first script process (because of `exec`) and only the `sudo`ed version will go forward. If the line after `exec sudo` gets executed, it means the shell failed to even start `sudo` and something is really wrong.

If the user is authorized to run the script, `sudo` may or may not request a password; if a wrong password is entered or the user is not authorized to run the script as root, a standard `sudo` error message will be displayed.

If succesful, `sudo` will start the script a second time, now running with root privileges. The `if` expression will now skip the `exec sudo...` step and continue into the rest of the script.

So the processes will be:

- parent: the command line session where the user runs the script
- child: initially the shell running the script as the user, but turns into `sudo` because of `exec`
- grandchild: a shell running the script as root.

Answer (score -2):

so here is your typical used case
1.in your  bash there are lines which  executes without sudo
2.also in your bash there are lines which needs a super user
3.after the execution of lines which required superused preivelage you want
the control back into your script and then go on with usual business

well if thats what you need here is a sample
#!/bin/bash
if [[  $(cat /proc/net/dev |grep br0) ]]; then
echo "Creating bridge"
pwd
cd ../../
cd /proc/sys/net
pwd
modprobe br_netfilter
cd bridge
sudo -s
for f in bridge-nf-*; do echo 0 > $f;done
brctl show
echo "type exit to continue"
cd ../../../../
cd /home/shino/Desktop/openwrt_virt
pwd

fi

just check the line sudo -s thats all you need save this into a bash and try thank me later