# How can we disconnect a file descriptor from any file?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, file-descriptors

In bash we can create a connection between a file descriptor and a file, e.g. by

```
exec > /path/to/myfile
```

which connects fd 1 to the file.

I was wondering how we can disconnect a fd from any file connected to it, so that the fd isn't connected to any file? Note that `/dev/null` and `/dev/tty` are files.

Thanks.

My purpose is to figure out [Does a shell automatically connect file descriptors 0, 1 and 2 to its controlling terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/446583/674), by disconnect fd 0, 1 and 2 in bash, before running `bash` in the same bash shell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is close the file descriptor which in Bourne-like shell is done with the `>&-` (defaults to fd 1) or `<&-` (defaults to fd 0) operator:

```
exec >&-
exec 1>&-
exec 1<&-
```

are all equivalent and result in a `close(1)` system call being made.

Note that it's generally a bad idea to close file descriptors 0, 1 and 2, as most commands expect those to be open (it's their stdin, stdout and stderr), and them opening a file could cause that file to inadvertently   become their stdin/stdout/stderr and what they print on stdout or stderr could end up being written in those files.

Comment: Thanks. My purpose is to figure out https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/446583/674, by disconnect fd 0, 1 and 2 in bash, before running `bash` in the same bash shell.