# What does the Unix login program/command do?

Tags: login, command

I am reading *APUE* and it keeps refering to the `login` program, but I still don't know what it is doing in my operating system (Ubuntu).

§8.11:

> Normally, the real user ID is set by the `login(1)` program when we log in and never changes. Because `login` is a superuser process, it sets all three user IDs when it calls setuid

`ps aux | grep login`:

```
root       840  0.0  0.0  70732  6120 ?        Ss   15:13   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
root      1120  0.0  0.0 419680  9468 ?        Sl   15:13   0:00 gdm-session-worker [pam/gdm-autologin]
tianhe    1151  0.0  0.1 445184 20540 ?        SLl  15:13   0:05 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
tianhe   10838  0.0  0.0  21536  1060 pts/0    S+   21:50   0:00 grep --color=auto login
```

So in short, what functionality does this `login` program provide for the OS?

Under what circumstances it is used or run?

Btw, how is `login` compared to `ssh`?

Comment: I Googled it before asking but did not find any useful posts explaining the use of it :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably login to a windowing session, in this case a display manager `xdm`, `gdm`, `kdm` … will log you in. However there are other ways to login. For example over a network we can use (as you have pointed out) `ssh`. If we login locally, but not into a windowing system, then we need a different login program. This is where login comes in.

Try pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>f1</kbd>, login then have a look at what processes are running. What logged you in.

Comment: Thank you. Combining with the answer by @JdBP, I seems to understand. However, `ctrl + alt + f1` does not prompt anything ( I am using Ubuntu) :(

Comment: That's because the `ctrl + alt + f#` switches between `vt#`, and your `gdm` login manager is likely running on `vt1`, which is reached from `ctrl + alt + f1`. Try `ctrl + alt + F2` through `F8` (sheesh, why doesn't <kbd>x</kbd> work in comments?)

Comment: @Rich Are you kidding me? My system crashed after I pressed `ctrl + alt + F2` :(

Comment: @rick you may have some hardware/driver problems (What graphic hardware are you using?).

Comment: Hmmm, I am using `product: GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB]`...

Comment: @Rick Nvidia: are you using the propriatory (non-free) drivers?

Comment: `01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB] (rev a1)
 Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB]
 Kernel driver in use: nvidia
 Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia`

Comment: Ah, yes, not the open source one. It's ok,don't waste your time. I barely use`ctrl + alt + F2` , but it's just I get nothing by pressing`ctrl + alt + F1` :D

Comment: @Rick I hear it is buggy, but have no experience (I don't use nvidia because of the poor support for old drivers. And the free driver suck because of poor documentation of the hardware.)

Comment: @Rick You have other issues if switching VTs crashes your system.

Answer (score 4):

## It isn't a command for you to run interactively.

> The `login` command is not normally entered on the command line.

<sup>— `login` manual.  IBM AIX 7.2</sup>

It used to be.  Back in the 1980s, this would work, and C-shell users even had a convenience `login` built-in command which would `exec` the external `login` program, overlaying the shell process with that program, which was set-UID to the superuser.

But operating systems do not work nowadays like BSD of the 1980s.  A *login session* (which is the type of session being discussed there, by the way) goes through too many one-way trapdoors (user security contexts, control groups, changed-UID "taint" markers, AIX `setsenv`, and so forth) for it to be feasible to correctly start a fresh login session for an arbitrary user from a process that is *already in* a user login session.

And in any case, because of the advent of PAM in the 1990s, the shell process that would be overlaid with the new `login` program is no longer the topmost process in the tree as it was in the 1980s.  It's now a child of a supervisory process, that is doing PAM session setup and teardown.

This is why "dæmonization" is a fallacy and this is why running `login` from within an existing login session is not really sensible.

## It is a system program.

`login` is invoked by *terminal login services*, usually directly, after the service or the service management infrastructure has set up some environment variables, opened the terminal device and initialized/pushed the line discipline, set it as the controlling terminal, and initialized the terminal with some control sequences.

- On AT&T Unix System 5 Release 4 back in 1987, these would be services managed by `ttymon`, part of the Service Access Facility.  You can still see these today on OpenSolaris and its derivatives such as Illumos and Schillix.
- On systemd Linux operating systems these are the `autovt@something` services (usually aliases for `getty@something` services).  This is the notable odd-one-out of the System 5 side of the universe, still using a `getty` program to invoke `login` when almost no-one else does any more.
- On operating systems using [the nosh toolset](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/) for service management, these are the `ttylogin@something` services.
- In the BSD side of the universe, if not using nosh service management, these are services spawned by process #1 according to the `/etc/ttys` table.

If you logged in on a virtual terminal, or a real terminal, it was `login` that prompted you for your password, and possibly for your user name as well, and then proceeded to invoke your interactive login shell.

`login` is not used by SSH login.  Nor is it used by *GUI* login.  Both of these operate differently, using other programs.  `login` expects to be talking to a terminal, with a Textual User Interface.

It *is* used by the old Berkeley rlogin system, but you should not be employing that nowadays.  Further discussion of the so-called Berkeley "r-" commands is way beyond the scope of this answer.  So I'll just say that this is something else that isn't done any more the way that it was in the 1980s.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard. "[Terminals](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/terminals.html)". *nosh Guide*. Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018).  [*`getty` spawned from `init` is a thing of the past.*](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/inittab-getty-is-history.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/446619/5132