# will the sleep command in this command ever be executed?

Tags: bash, exec

Motivated by [How can I change my command to run without superuser privilleges but with the changed limit value?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446539/how-can-i-change-my-command-to-run-without-superuser-privilleges-but-with-the-ch?noredirect=1#comment810766_446539), in a bash shell, if I run

```
exec su $LOGNAME && sleep 100
```

will the sleep command ever be executed?

I think not, because `exec su $LOGNAME` will replace the shell in the current process with another shell. When I exit the new shell normally (for `&&`), the process terminates and there is no process to execute the sleep command.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't. Either the `exec` succeeds, and the shell is replaced, or the `exec` fails in which case `&&` doesn't run the following command. `exec somcmd || echo fail` or `exec 2>somefile && echo ok` would be different, though.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering why `exec 2>somefile` hangs https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447311/why-does-exec-2somefile-hang

Answer (score 0):

No it will not, check:

```
ksh93
$ exec /bin/echo bla && sleep 1 && echo foo
bla
```

You will get back to the previous shell and the `exec` replaces the ksh93 instance completely.